# Can't run Phoenix server. Can't find erlang/lib/parsetools-2.1.8

Tags: ubuntu, elixir, phoenix-framework

```
~/Desktop/phoenix_sandbox/app$ mix phx.server
==> gettext
Compiling 1 file (.yrl)
/usr/lib/erlang/lib/parsetools-2.1.8/include/yeccpre.hrl: no such file or directory

could not compile dependency :gettext, "mix compile" failed. You can recompile this dependency with "mix deps.compile gettext", update it with "mix deps.update gettext" or clean it with "mix deps.clean gettext"
```

I've been going around in circles with the error. I installed "parse tools" (whatever it is). If I do "mix deps.clean gettext" it takes me in circles and I get the same error. I'm on Ubuntu

Comment: have you installed erlang? and how did you install elixir?

Comment: I installed elixir and erlang per the instructions at the elixir site. I had some other problems so at this point I might have installed all kinds of crap trying to fix this.

Comment: I will suggest to delete it and install it through ASDF.. and try again

Comment: I  get errors with missing packages all over the place.

Comment: No matter what I do I get "It appears that a required development package 'libncurses5-dev' is not installed."  and: " * documentation  : 
 *                  xsltproc is missing.
 *                  fop is missing.
 *                  xmllint is missing.
 *                  The documentation cannot be built.
"

Comment: your solutions seem to be this https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-erlang

Answer (score 10):

`erlang-dev` package is needed to provide `yeccpre.hrl`

(apt-file or google for debian's package repo can help identify these situations, here is the list of files erlang-dev includes in buster, parsetools version is different however your erlang package set should correct this for you:
https://packages.debian.org/buster/arm64/erlang-dev/filelist )

Comment: this work perfectly for me, I am using WSL2.

Comment: `apt-file search yeccpre` will tell you which package the file belongs to. For me it was `erlang-dev` and installing it worked for me on Ubuntu also.

Answer (score 1):

For Debian / Linux distributions the `erlang-dev` package is required to start Phoenix:

```
sudo apt install erlang-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Erlang installed via package managers is not a good way to go, because they will not include all you need, and sometimes they put some libraries in places they are not meant to be, and then some tools just don't work properly.

I recommend you to use Erlang Solutions releases instead, and if you don't like to use Docker, then you can try to replicate what I am doing in the [Dockerfile](https://gitlab.com/exadra37-docker/elixir/elixir-docker-stack/-/blob/94f1585d7631fea156b76c1fb1f56dbfd616223e/docker/build/debian.esl.Dockerfile) of my Elixir Docker Stack or just use the below bash script.

### Install an Elixir Phoenix stack in Ubuntu 18.04

My Elixir Docker Stack started from an old bash script I was using to install Erlang, Elixir, Phoenix and NodeJS, thus I will add it here for your convenience.

Save this bash file `install-stack.sh` into your computer:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

set -eu

Main() {

    local ERLANG_VERSION=${1? Missing Erlang version. Check the latest version at https://www.erlang-solutions.com/resources/download.html}
    local ERLANG_DOWNLOAD_URL=https://packages.erlang-solutions.com/erlang/debian/pool/esl-erlang_${ERLANG_VERSION}-1~ubuntu~bionic_amd64.deb

    local ELIXIR_VERSION=${2? Missing Erlang version. Check the latest version at https://www.erlang-solutions.com/resources/download.html}
    local ELIXIR_DOWNLOAD_URL=https://packages.erlang-solutions.com/erlang/debian/pool/elixir_${ELIXIR_VERSION}-1~ubuntu~bionic_all.deb

    local PHOENIX_VERSION="${3? Missing Phoenix version to install!!!}"

    local NODEJS_VERSION="${4? Missing NodeJS version to install!!!}"

    apt update
    apt -y upgrade
    apt -y -q install --no-install-recommends \
        ca-certificates \
        curl \
        build-essential \
        procps \
        libncurses5 \
        libwxbase3.0-0v5 \
        libwxgtk3.0-0v5 \
        libsctp1

    apt -y -f install

    printf "\nERLANG DOWNLOAD URL: ${ERLANG_DOWNLOAD_URL}\n"
    curl -fsSL -o esl.deb "${ERLANG_DOWNLOAD_URL}"
    dpkg -i esl.deb
    rm -f esl.deb

    printf "\nELIXIR DOWNLOAD URL: ${ELIXIR_DOWNLOAD_URL}\n"
    curl -fsSL -o elixir.deb "${ELIXIR_DOWNLOAD_URL}"
    dpkg -i elixir.deb
    rm -f elixir.deb

    printf "\nPHOENIX VERSION: ${PHOENIX_VERSION}\n"

    # installs the package manager
    mix local.hex --force

    # installs rebar and rebar3
    mix local.rebar --force

    mkdir -p "${HOME}/bin"
    ln -s "${HOME}"/.mix/rebar "${HOME}"/bin/rebar
    ln -s "${HOME}"/.mix/rebar3 "${HOME}"/bin/rebar3

    mix archive.install --force hex phx_new ${PHOENIX_VERSION}

    # INSTALL NODEJS
    printf "\nNODEJS VERSION: ${NODEJS_VERSION}\n"
    curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_"${NODEJS_VERSION}".x | sh -
    apt install -y -q --no-install-recommends nodejs
}

Main ${@}
```

Uninstall Erlang, Elixir and Phoenix from your system.

Install the Elixir Phoenix stack with `bash install-stack.sh <erlang-version> <elixir-version> <phoenix-version> <nodejs-version>`:

```
bash install-stack.sh 22.3.3 1.10.3 1.5.1 10
```

Now test it works:

```
mix phx.new hello --no-ecto && cd hello && mix test
```

Output:

```
...

Finished in 0.03 seconds
3 tests, 0 failures

...
```

The script was tested inside a docker container with:

```
docker run --rm -it -v $PWD/install-stack.sh:/install-stack.sh ubuntu:18.04 bash
```